# phpMyAdmin: #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I am getting in phpMyAdmin the famous #1045 error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

This is my /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:

```
/**
 * Server(s) configuration
 */
$i = 0;
// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use $cfg['Servers'][0].
// You can disable a server config entry by setting host to ''.
$i++;

/* Authentication type */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
/* Optional: User for advanced features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
/* Optional: Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you configured your root password for MySQL during installation? Do you have MySQL listening on a unix socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize all the configuration lines are commented out? You need to uncomment and fill-in those fields for anything to happen. I think including this one would be sufficient (assuming you want it to prompt you for a username/password):

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Answer (score 0):

execute following command

$ mysqladmin -u root password abcd

and use the password in config file as 'abcd'

or replace your password with 'abcd'

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the below lines and fill the correct info:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';


/* Optional: User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = ''; /*You can leave it blank, PHPmyadmin will ask you the user name and password */
```